# Geting Backspace in front of string in Typed.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, web

As my below code on excuting iam getting a backspace cursor fixed in front of string. i tried some way but it didn't work. Is anyone aware of how to remove it from the front of the string. Please Help me

```js
$(function() {
  $("h2 .first").typed({
    strings: ["Hello "],
    typeSpeed: 0,
    callback: function() {
      showThis();
    },

  });

  function showThis() {

    $("span.second").typed({
      strings: ["First", "Second", "Third"],
      backDelay: 1500,
      typeSpeed: 100,
      backSpeed: 100,
      loop: true,

    });

  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.typed cursor {
  display: none;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4.125em;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/js/typed.custom.js"></script>
<div class="header">

  <h2><span class="first"></span><span class="second"></span></h2>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a function in your callback for the .first typed function that removes the cursor. 
$('.typed-cursor').remove();
Or document.querySelector('.typed-cursor').remove();

```js
$(function() {
  $("h2 .first").typed({
    strings: ["Hello "],
    typeSpeed: 0,
    callback: function() {
      showThis();
      document.querySelector('.typed-cursor').remove();
    },

  });

  function showThis() {

    $("span.second").typed({
      strings: ["First", "Second", "Third"],
      backDelay: 1500,
      typeSpeed: 100,
      backSpeed: 100,
      loop: true,

    });

  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.typed cursor {
  display: none;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4.125em;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/js/typed.custom.js"></script>
<div class="header">

  <h2><span class="first"></span><span class="second"></span></h2>


</div>
```

Comment: Can you show me in a code snippet.        It would be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: @AdarshGoldar Added.

Comment: Also worth noting, regular javascript (as shown in the snippet) only removes the 1 cursor as it only grabs the first element in an array of class elements. Using JQuery seems to grab all the cursors which feel somewhat unexpected @AdarshGoldar

Comment: Thank You Trevor.